# Does chrome.alarms.clearAll() affect other extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, alarm

I'm using the function to clear my extension's alarms when the user changes their settings.

`chrome.alarms.clear('alarm-name')` caused some inconsistencies, so removing all of them was a pretty straightforward alternative, but I don't want to affect the user experience regarding other extensions, and didn't find anything related to this question in the docs.

Comment: Only your own alarms are removed. Everything is isolated per extension, just like everything is isolated per origin in the web.